# when i try to open the gender page w/c is the last one in my urls.py this error occurs and raises the wrong app views. how to fix?

Tags: python, django

**Error:**
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/men/
Raised by:  app.views.productinshop
No Shop matches the given query.

**urls.py**

urlpatterns += patterns('',

```
url(r'^$', 'app.views.shop', name='shop'),
url(r'^shops/$', 'app.views.shops', name='shops'),
url(r'^(?P<shop_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.productinshop', name='productbyshop'),
url(r'^(?P<shop_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<gender_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.shopandgender', name='shopandgender'),
url(r'^(?P<shop_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<gender_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<catalog_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.shopgenderandcatalog', name='shopgenderandcatalog'),
url(r'^(?P<shop_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<gender_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<catalog_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.shopgendercatalogandcategory', name='shopgendercatalogandcategory'),
url(r'^(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.productdetails', name='productdetails'),
url(r'^(?P<gender_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.gender', name='gender'),
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, url patterns are matched in the order they are listed, and after the first match is found, no further searching is done.

In your case, you have three exact same patterns:

```
url(r'^(?P<shop_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.productinshop', name='productbyshop'),
url(r'^(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.productdetails', name='productdetails'),
url(r'^(?P<gender_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.views.gender', name='gender'),
```

When django sees `http://localhost:8000/men/` the very first pattern that matches is the one that points to `app.views.productinshop`, so django stops searching further and that's the view that gets called.

To prevent this, you need to change your url schemes.

Comment: thank you i have solved the problem already n sorry for the late reply.